# set instance variable equal to only specific model parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
def place
  @place = Activity.find(params[:id])
end
```

How would I choose specific params? We have activity.address1,2, zip state etc and just need an instance variable we can use which is equal to just the address attributes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your question. Would you try rewording or adding some examples of what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do something like:

```
def place
  @place ||= Activity.find(params[:id])
  @address_attributes = @place.attributes.slice('address_1', 'address_2', 'zip', 'state')
end
```

In which case you'll have an instance variable that contains a hash of the specified  attributes that you might use something like:

```
@address_attributes['address_1']
```

Personally, I find typing the `''` around the key values annoying and prefer using symbols. In which case you might do something like:

```
def place
  @place ||= Activity.find(params[:id])
  @address_attributes = @place.attributes.with_indifferent_access.slice(:address_1, :address_2, :zip, :state)
end
```

Which you would use something like:

```
@address_attributes[:address_1]
```

But, even the brackets and symbols are a little annoying. So, you might do something like:

```
def place
  @place ||= Activity.find(params[:id])
  @address_attributes = OpenStruct.new(@place.attributes.with_indifferent_access.slice(:address_1, :address_2, :zip, :state))
end
```

Which you could then use something like:

```
@address_attributes.address_1
```

Now, personally, I don't like that long line in the `place` method, so I would be tempted to do something like:

```
def place
  @place ||= Activity.find(params[:id])
  @address_attributes = get_address_attributes
end

private

def get_address_attributes
  OpenStruct.new(
    @place.
      attributes.
      with_indifferent_access.
      slice(
        :address_1, 
        :address_2, 
        :zip, 
        :state
      )
  )
end
```

Now, if this is all in a controller, and you're setting the `@address_attributes` variable just so that you can use it in a view, then maybe that's good enough.

But, if you're using the `@address_attributes` variable elsewhere in the current instance, then you might consider doing something like:

```
attr_accessor *%w(
  address_attributes
).freeze

delegate *%w(
  address_1
  address_2
  zip
  state
), to: :address_attributes, prefix: place

def place
  @place ||= Activity.find(params[:id])
  @address_attributes = get_address_attributes
end

private

def get_address_attributes
  OpenStruct.new(
    @place.
      attributes.
      with_indifferent_access.
      slice(
        :address_1, 
        :address_2, 
        :zip, 
        :state
      )
  )
end
```

In which case, you could make calls like:

```
place_address_1
```

Which seems a lot nicer than something like:

```
@address_attributes['address_1']
```